# RewriteCond check if directory exists with an index file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a rewrite for all requests EXCEPT if the URL points to:

- An existing file
- A directory with an index file

So I have the following that should have dealt with it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php [QSA]
```

But when I navigate to a folder that contains an `index.php` (and yes I have checked that `DirectoryIndex` is set to `index.php`), it still performs the rewrite.

The funny thing I also found is that if I had a `.htaccess` in that folder with `RewriteEngine on` (just that), then the rewrite rule above works...

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check for the directory part:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index\.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php [QSA,L]
```

Also:

> The funny thing I also found is that if I had a .htaccess in that folder with RewriteEngine on (just that), then the rewrite rule above works...

This is because rewrite rules in subdirectories have precedence over any rules in parent directories. So if you have a subdirectory with `RewriteEngine On`, with no rules, then that means that subdirectory has precedence over rewrite rules in the parent directory and there are no rules. (a bit confusing).

Comment: I think your first two conditions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Award answer to this one because it also explained the "funny thing..." part :)

Comment: Okay, now you can have my +1 :)

Comment: Didn't work for my site, unfortunately. Browser complains of too many redirects. All other conditions/rules commented out.

Answer (score 5):

Try this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ redirect.php [L]
```